# View requests made by Firefox extension / add-on

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions, firefox-developer-tools

How do I view requests and errors made by a Firefox extension? They don't show in the usual tab Inspector tool.

In Chrome, it's

```
chrome://extensions/ > Details > Inspect Views (background page)
```

That opens DevTools for the Chrome extension. I don't see an option for this in Firefox.

Comment: I have updated the answer with the one that worked for you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Copy this one and paste it into a new tab.

```
about:debugging#/runtime/this-firefox
```

Comment: That shows what addons I have installed, but not the requests made by those add-ons.

Comment: about:debugging#/runtime/this-firefox

Comment: What about this one?

Comment: Yes, that did it Thanks!

Comment: You included a lot of extra links that don't answer the question. If you just include the actual answer, then I'll accept it.

Comment: @user984003 I have updated the answer with the one that worked for you